# What are the different ways in declaring functions in javascript and when to use which?

Tags: javascript

I see that in javascript, sometimes you can write

`function thisIsMyFunction(options) {}`

and u can write

`var myFunction = function(input) {}`

also you can write

`function() {}`

When are the different declaration used?

Comment: There’s also `var myFunction = function myFunction(input) {}`.

Comment: It doesn't really matter, just how ever you prefer.

Comment: This has been discussed many times before.  I will search for a duplicate.

Comment: `function thisIsMyFunction(options) {}` - a function with name `thisIsMyFunction` and `var myFunction = function(input) {}` - a function with name `myFunction`. no difference and last `function() {}` - a function without any name just like anonymous function.

Comment: A complete guide to what you're looking for - https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/

Comment: @Braj Technically, `var a=function(){}` creates an _anonymous_ function _referenced_ by `a`; it’s not a named function.

Comment: FWIW, `function() {}` by itself is a syntax error.

Comment: Main difference between the first two: `function a(){}` is hoisted (you can use it as a function, even if the function is defined later in the code), whereas from `var a=function(){}` only the `var a;` part is being hoisted and it’s not a function _yet_. `(function(){})` creates an anonymous function, even if `var … =` is before it. Other than that, there isn’t much of a practical difference.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks for correcting my understanding.